# SQL CASE statement returns error

Tags: sql, case

Hi I have select CASE statement in DB2:

```
case when actualfinish is not null then dec (( timestampdiff(
  4, 
  char(actualfinish - reportdate))/60.00),10,2)
else 'not'
 end
```

It returns me error.
If I delete ELSE part there is no error and calculation is done.

```
    case when actualfinish is not null then dec (( timestampdiff(
      4, 
      char(actualfinish - reportdate))/60.00),10,2)
end
```

If I change THEN part to something like

```
  case when actualfinish is not null then 'Yes'
    else 'not'
     end
```

also there is no error.

But for my complete SQL query - can't find an error.
Thanks

Comment: What datatype does dec() function return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue here is that `dec` function returns a decimal datatype in the else part of the CASE statement you are returning a VARCHAR, hence the issue.

In your second version
`case when actualfinish is not null then 'Yes'
    else 'not'
     end`

Both the `when` and `else` are returning same datatype hence the query runs fine.

Change your else to send a decimal equivalent value and it should execute fine.

Update:

Use this version if you can return decimal as a string:

```
CASE 
    WHEN actualfinish IS NOT NULL THEN CHAR(DEC((TIMESTAMPDIFF(4, CHAR(actualfinish - reportdate))/60.00),10,2))
    ELSE 'not'
END
```

Comment: Chandu thanks but how to solve this then? My else part must return 'not' to indicate that actualfinish is null and my firts part then must return float value to show calculated value for difference. I REALLY must have both in this type - float and string. How to solve this then? Thanks

Comment: As I mentioned return same datatype i WHEN and ELSE be it Decimal or VARCHAR which ever suits the requirments

Comment: can I somehow trick SQL query and convert this decimal value in THEN part to String value? What will be the correct expression for that? Thanks

Comment: Am no Db2 expert.. Looks like you can use CHAR function to convert the decimal to String. e.g: `CASE 
 WHEN actualfinish IS NOT NULL THEN CHAR(DEC((TIMESTAMPDIFF(4, CHAR(actualfinish - reportdate))/60.00),10,2))
 ELSE 'not'
END`